# Should I use CSS3 media queries to deliver different image sizes for retina display devices?

Tags: css, cordova, media-queries

Many similar questions have been asked here before. I believe mine is slightly unique.
I have developed a mobile app with JQM + Cordova/PhoneGap.

Originally I used big images (targeted towards retina display devices) and used responsive css to scale image down as needed. The problem with this approach that older devices end up having to download big images and these devices would not have the same processing 'grunt' that newer retina devices have - causing unnecessary overheads.

I decided to use css background images because I have heard they load faster than image HTML tags (as everything is loaded in css first) and then use css3 media queries like below:

```
@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 1), 
(max-resolution: 163dpi) { 
.pic #point1 {background-image: url(../img/baby/nonretina/Baby-TP1-Role-Models.jpg); border: 2px solid #ccc;}
}

@media 
(-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2), 
(min-resolution: 326dpi) { 
.pic #point1 {background-image: url(../img/baby/retina/Baby-TP1-Role-Models.jpg); border: 2px solid #ccc;}
}
```

Now comes the issue, I have got stacks of images within my app (hundreds) so my css file is going to be quite large. Considering my app will need to load the css in the first page/view (index.html), will this negatively impact on my app load time? Should I still use this approach or revert to the former approach?

I just feel like a big css file with heaps of media queries may not be the answer to optimise images within my app for both retina and non retina devices...

Comment: [Interesting read here on Smashing](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/08/20/towards-retina-web/)

Comment: I think this question is fine. "Is there a more efficient method?" - Yes, but there are drawbacks for each method used. I think that article will give you the best idea of pros and cons.

Comment: I don't think its a silly question Aleem. I am using the standard approach and offering two sets of images. I think your reference to @2x is something in xcode or just a naming convention (I have used that convention before). I just get the feeling that packing everything into my css file is going to end up with over 1000 lines of conditional code and it will bog my app down. Thanks for the link misterManSam.

Comment: LOL, I was actually following information on http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/07/22/simple-responsive-images-with-css-background-images/ on how to properly construct css3 media queries! I like the new webkit implementation of media queries that Apple has recently introduced. Doubt older iphones will support that yet, but definitely something to keep in mind.

Comment: Be aware that some devices may download all background images, even if they don't use them all. That's partly why I prefer the method suggested here: http://blog.netvlies.nl/design-interactie/retina-revolution/. In Essence, save the image at a large size but low quality. When it is resized in the browser, it looks good on all devices. There are new elements/attributes coming out to help with this also, but they are a way off yet.

Answer (score 1):

Putting every image in your CSS can be burdensome. I've used ralph.m's method for small images. But the new W3C standard, the [picture element](http://responsiveimages.org/), already supported on Chrome, Firefox and Opera. It will let devices decide the best image to download. The [PictureFill polyfill](https://github.com/scottjehl/picturefill/) lets you use the picture element now on any Javascript-enabled device.

```
<picture>
  <source media="(min-width: 40em)" srcset="nonretinaBaby.jpg 1x,
    retinaBaby.jpg 2x">
  <source srcset="nonretinaBaby.jpg 1x, retinaBaby.jpg 2x">
  <img src="fallback.jpg" alt="">
</picture>
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch for the suggestion but is it wise to rely on JavaScript to do the image processing on mobile devices? I see that it is supported by Firefox, Chrome and Opera - but does it support WebKit Safari? It does seem like a great solution though.

Comment: WebKit/Safari has already implemented the related srcset syntax:       <img src="small.jpg"
     srcset="large.jpg 1024w, medium.jpg 640w, small.jpg 320w"
     sizes="(min-width: 36em) 33.3vw, 100vw"
     alt="A rad wolf" />

Comment: Thanks Michael. I will implement your solution soon to test if it works well on mobile devices without bogging down the processor with JS. Right now with all the CSS I am using, it's most likely affecting my app's speed of response.