# Does "background-size:cover" reduces file size?

Tags: css

For the example i have 1080x1920px dimensions picture and my div is 100x100px. So will "background-size:cover" load 100x100px file, or 1080x1920px and then apply it to the div? How can i reduce image file size if I want to cover my div?

Comment: `background-size:cover` will load full size of picture

Comment: "CSS" - that you have tagged - stands for Cascading Style Sheets. It is designed for styling purposes (separating the content from presentation), not more than this.

Comment: Regarding "How can i reduce image file size", these links on adaptive images might be helpful: [Adaptive Images](http://adaptive-images.com/), [One Solution To Responsive Images](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/02/03/one-solution-to-responsive-images/), [Deliver Different Image Sizes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24358259/should-i-use-css3-media-queries-to-deliver-different-image-sizes-for-retina-disp)

Answer (score 1):

`background-size:cover` = Scale the background image to be as large as possible so that the background area is completely covered by the background image. Some parts of the background image may not be in view within the background positioning area

Basically it zooms in until the inner most edges are touching the side, which means that some of the image may be cut off unlike 100% where all of the image will be visible.

## See this [LINK](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_background-size&preval=cover) for example

---

**CSS3** <sub>background-size</sub>

This is possible to do in CSS3 with `background-size`.

All modern browsers support this, so unless you need to support old browsers, this is the way to do it.

<sub>**Supported browsers:**</sub>

<sup>Mozilla Firefox 4.0+ (Gecko 2.0+), Microsoft Internet Explorer 9.0+, Opera 10.0+, Safari 4.1+ (webkit 532) and Chrome 3.0+.</sup>

```css
.stretch{
/* Will stretch to specified width/height */
  background-size: 200px 150px;
}
.stretch-content{
/* Will stretch to width/height of element */
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.resize-width{
/* width: 150px, height: auto to retain aspect ratio */
  background-size: 150px Auto;
}
.resize-height{
/* height: 150px, width: auto to retain aspect ratio */
  background-size: Auto 150px;
}
.resize-fill-and-clip{ 
  /* Resize to fill and retain aspect ratio.
     Will cause clipping if aspect ratio of box is different from image. */ 
  background-size: cover;
}
.resize-best-fit{
/* Resize to best fit and retain aspect ratio.
   Will cause gap if aspect ratio of box is different from image. */ 
  background-size: contain;
}
```

In particular, I like the `cover` and `contain` values that gives us new power of control that we didn't have before.

### Round

You can also use `background-size: round` that have a meaning in combination with repeat:

```css
.resize-best-fit-in-repeat{
/* Resize to best fit in a whole number of times in x-direction */ 
  background-size: round auto; /* Height: auto is to keep aspect ratio */
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

This will adjust the image width so it fits a whole number of times in the background positioning area.

---

*Additional note*
If the size you need is static pixel size, it is still smart to physically resize the actual image. This is both to improve quality of the resize (given that your image software does a better job than the browsers), and to save bandwidth if the original image is larger than what to display.